# Vinyl Plank laid on top of wet adhesive: Will it ever dry?

Tags: flooring, adhesive, vinyl

I laid down the glue and troweled it out then laid down the tile before glue was tacky. Will it ever dry? Or will it continue to seep up through the cracks?

Comment: What brand of flooring did you use? Did you use the manufacturer's recommended glue or something else? Are you experiencing any actual issues or are you speculating that there will be a problem? How long have you waited since initial install before asking? Please [edit] this additional info into your question.

Comment: What's under the adhesive? If it's something porous, that may be enough to help it cure.

Comment: How soon can you walk on it is the question. "For a ***minimum* of 24 hours** after your new vinyl floor is installed, protect all the seamed areas, **don't walk on them** or the seam sealer. Keep the room at **68° F or greater for at least 2 days** after installation to allow the adhesives to setup properly."

Comment: Not sure where these answers were going so I had to google it :  "**Wait for up to half an hour** for your vinyl adhesive to become sticky and the texture to become tacky. The instructions for use on your adhesive of choice will provide you with any further information or timings that you need to be aware of when fitting your LVT flooring." " However, you will need to work alongside the clock as the adhesive will **begin to dry over the course of around 2 hours**. " https://www.flooringdirect.co.uk/lvt-fitting-guide-i148

Comment: People actually do that? That would make installing it take a week. Every four feet you have to wait a half an hour? Yeah that ain't happening.

Answer (score 1):

It will eventually dry or get to a point where there's not enough glue to force through the cracks. The glue needs air to harden and you've cut off the air supply. The surfaces to the subfloor and planks will eventually harden but the stuff in the middle, who knows.

Answer (score -1):

If vinyl planks are laid on top of wet adhesive, the adhesive will not dry effectively and may cause issues with the vinyl plank installation. The adhesive needs to dry before the vinyl planks are installed to ensure that they adhere properly to the floor.

If the adhesive is still wet and the vinyl planks have already been installed, it may take a long time for the adhesive to dry completely. In some cases, the adhesive may not dry at all, leading to problems with the vinyl planks, such as warping, lifting, or buckling.

It is best to remove the vinyl planks and allow the adhesive to dry completely before reinstalling them. This will ensure a proper installation and prevent any issues with the vinyl planks in the future. If you're unsure about the state of the adhesive or the installation, it's best to consult with a professional flooring installer.

Comment: FYI this user copied this text chat GPT